# How to locate an image on the screen with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

When a certain image of a button popups up, I want to click that image. How can this be done with AppleScript?

Comment: what application are you talking about and what is the point of this exercise ? more information is needed

Comment: I'm talking about buttons that appear in a webpage. I want to know how to automate clicking certain things when they pop up.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [project SIKULI](http://sikuli.org/).